# Weyl group of complex Lie group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group with maximal torus $T$. The Weyl group is defined by
$$W:=N_G(T)/T.$$
Now, $G$ has a complexification $G_{\Bbb C}$ with maximal torus $T_{\Bbb C}$ which is the complexification of $T$.

> **Question:** Is $W$ naturally isomorphic to the group $W_{\Bbb C}:=N_{G_{\Bbb C}}(T_{\Bbb C})/T_{\Bbb C}$?

---

**Attempt:** Since $T\subseteq T_{\Bbb C}$, we have a natural group homomorphism
$$N_G(T)/T\longrightarrow N_{G_{\Bbb C}}(T_{\Bbb C})/T_{\Bbb C},\quad gT\longmapsto gT_{\Bbb C}.$$
Moreover, it is easy to see that it is injective. But I am not sure if it is surjective.

Also, $W$ and $W_{\Bbb C}$ both act on ${\frak t}_{\Bbb C}$ by the adjoint representation and it seems natural that these two actions are the same. Is that true?

Comment: The answer is yes, the natural homomorphism is an isomorphism, but I don't recall right now the argument that makes this obvious. Basically the normaliser in the complexification cannot be larger than the complexification of the normaliser. I suppose one could use the complex-conjugation action with which the complexification gets equipped: if a complex group element $g$ normalises, then so does its complex conjugate $\overline g$, and presumably this leads to an element in $N_G(T)$ with the same action on $T$ as $g$.